# static UITableViewCell how to prevent Contenttview selection

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have `UIPickerView` inside the static cell and `UIPickerView` selection works fine. However. If the user clicks outside the `UIPickerView` it selects the cell and creates the gray background. I want to disable the user from selecting the cell and highlighting gray, but should only be able to select the `UIPickerView` inside that cell.

How can I do that?

I tried:

```
   override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell {
     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"CellIdentifier", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell


    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none

    return cell
    }
```

Now static cell won't even display.

How can I achieve what I want.

Comment: try giving your cell a background color and check cell should be there.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the selection of the cells in tableview:

```
   yourTableView.allowsSelection = false
```

Answer (score 0):

select tableview in storyboard and make it `no Selection`

[image]